# Mockito is not throwing an exception

Tags: mocking, mockito

May be its duplicate question. But I didn't find any answer to slove my problem.

I'm trying to throw the exception using mockito using below code, but mockito is not throwing. Is there any wrong with this?

```java
when(employeeRepository.save(any(Employee.class), anyLong())).thenThrow(DuplicateKeyException.class);
```

Comment: Is save executed in method under test? On the same instance of employeeRepository mock?

Comment: yes. its executed.

Comment: How about sharing the actual minimal test that should use that mock?

Comment: Show the imports used in the test file. You tagged your question with both Mockito and EasyMock. is that intentional?

Comment: But its throwing InvocationTargetException.  But with when(employeeRepository.save(any(), eq(employeeId))).thenReturn(expectedDetails); test cases run properly

Comment: It was my bad. I had imported wrong class. issue fixed now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `save(any(), any()))` if it is succeeded, then the values might be different during execution of your original code `save(any(Employee.class), anyLong()))`

```
when(employeeRepository.save(any(), any())).thenThrow(new DuplicateKeyException());
```

Comment: I tried this before. So got InvocationTargetException, so I tried as above

Comment: I have modified the answer a little bit could try the above?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure without the target code, try to use doThrow()

```
doThrow(new DuplicateKeyException()).when(employeeRepository).save(any(Employee.class), anyLong());
```

Comment: Still no luck. Target code : `@Override
 public Reward save(Employee employee, long employeeId) { // code to save employee using jdbcTemplate.update()` We have unique key in DB, if duplicate employee Id is trying to save, then exception will thrown

Comment: It was my bad. I had imported wrong class. issue fixed now. Thank you