# How to JUnit test try catch block

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, try-catch

I am not sure how to trigger a scenario which would allow me to test the catch block in the following piece of code:

```
public static String createSOAPFaultServerError(final Exception cause) {
    String result = null;
    logger.error("Creating SOAP fault:", cause);
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error creating SOAP fault", e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: mock something within the try block, and have it throw an Exception. but that 'll just catch, you won't be able to unit test the logger (unless of course you also mock the logger)

Comment: I am able to successfully test the try block, but I'm having a hard time to understand how to test the catch block. I can't get it to trigger.

Comment: I explained how to trigger it in my first comment

Comment: If you are using `Mockito` you can easily do this by using` doThrow(...).when(...)` or `when(...).thenThrow(...)` this will allow you to enter the catch clause and you can mock `logger` and `verify()` it has been called

Comment: You can find this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760422/mockito-is-not-throwing-an-exception/62772229#62772229